# Question about Hom(V, W)

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Question: Fix a vector v ∈ V. Prove that the evaluation map L ↦ L(v): Hom(V, W) → W is a linear transformation.

I don’t understand what is Hom(V, W). Can anyone give me some hints on proving this?

Comment: $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)=\{f:V\to W\mid f\text{ is a homomorphism}\}$. If $V,W$ are vector space, then it is the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Hom(V,W)$ is the set of all linear transformations from $V$ to $W$. It can be proved that it is also a vector space over the same field as $V$ and $W$. (the operations are sum of linear transformations and multiplying a linear transformation by a scalar)